# Is it okay to use "that" after "when"?

Tags: grammar

I heard someone saying that
"it was when my father was working as a counselor that he built his house".

It seems okay but it feels a little awkward at the sametime, but I don't know
why I feel that way.

Is there any grammatical issue with the sentence?

Comment: It is perfectly correct and fluent to this US English speaker.  It's a way of emphasizing the specific time.  You can find examples of this kind of structure in Google Books, for example ["It was when he stopped that..."](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&ei=DuP4WoPXAu_s5gKF2azYCw&q=%22it+was+when+he+stopped+that%22&oq=%22it+was+when+he+stopped+that%22&gs_l=psy-ab.3...1967.2034.0.2157.2.2.0.0.0.0.91.155.2.2.0....0...1c.1.64.psy-ab..0.0.0....0.BNgiTIHTsI0)

Comment: It's just a more formal version of "My father built his house when working as a counsellor."